# Cleaning up thread submitted using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

My code is as follows:

```
public Future<String> getFuture() {
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
    //do something
    return "test string";
  });
  executorService.shutDown(); // is this correct?
  return future;
}
```

I am calling this service from other class to get the future:

```
 Future<String> future = getFuture();
 String result = future.get();
 future.cancel(true); // will this assure that there wont be any thread leak?
```

Now out of `executorService.shutDown()` and `future.cancel(true)` which will assure that there wont be thread leaks?

Note that after calling `future.cancel(true)` when I check currently running threads in the result of `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` I can still find the thread where future executed.

Comment: After you retrieve the future value, have you checked the currently running threads?

Comment: Yes, `shutDown()` is correct. There is no thread leak. You might see the thread stick around for a while, but it would be a major bug if this could cause a thread leak.

Comment: @efekctive yes, I have updated the code to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @Kayaman doe's calling executorService.shutDown() before calling future.get() guarantees that it won't interrupt the execution of future task? I am confused as documentation of shutDown states that "This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution."

Comment: that is the way to do it. If there was a leak you will notice immediately

Comment: No, it doesn't guarantee it. You really shouldn't be creating an executor inside the method in the first place.

Comment: @efekctive So do I actually need to keep executorService.shutDown() and future.cancel(true) both or only calling future.cancel(true) should be enough?

Comment: You need to move the executor outside the method. Your logic as mentioned above needs to change

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question!

There is no point in creating a **service** within a method to then throw it away right there.

Creating that service instance doesn't come for free. The whole idea of this abstraction is to ensure to make **efficient** usage of infrastructure elements!

In other words: step back and rework your design; so that this service becomes a **field** of some class for example! And yes, that might turn out to be complicated. But most likely, spending time in that corner will pay out much more long term - compared to continuing the approach shown in your question.

Answer (score 0):

- It is a bad idea to create an executor then throw it away in each method call.

> Now out of executorService.shutDown() and future.cancel(true) which will assure that there wont be thread leaks?

none of them.
executorService.shutdown() will just keep running the current tasks and reject new submitted tasks.

future.cancel(true) will interrupt the corresponding task if it is currently running (but it is your responsability to check if the task was interrupted and finish the execution of the task as soon as possible)

> Note that after calling future.cancel(true) when I check currently running threads in the result of Thread.getAllStackTraces() I can still find the thread where future executed.

as I mentioned before, future.cancel(true) doesn't stop the thread. it only sends an interruption.

Comment: I used executorService.shutDownNow() and looks like it is cleaning up the thread.

Comment: that is not the way shutDownNow() works.  please read the documentation :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--